# cannot enter security code # in my 2005 accord

Tags: honda, accord

After cleaning my battery terminals I went to reset my radio security. My problem is that while the word "code" is supposed to show, I only see the letters "CO". If you try to enter the code number, the error message comes up.?????

Answer (score 1):

I think you have locked it too much. Try removing the batery and re-doing the steps again.

Remember its the buttons 1 and 6 pressed together at the same time while you try to turn it on again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you press 1&6 for 15 seconds & then while still holding 1&6 down press the power button 4 numbers will pop up just press 2 & the radio will be back to normal! I just had to do it to my 2005 Honda Accord! Hope this helps! God bless!